# Xcode gives Apple Mach-O linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, mach-o, undefined-symbol

I just compiled a project and Xcode returns these two errors which don't seem to be my code's fault. How do I fix them?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Blur) boxblurImageWithBlur:] in UIImage+Blur.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Care to show the related code?

Comment: The problem is with the `UIImage+Blur.m` file. It's looking for a symbol named `vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888`. You need to include the .m (or .c) file that has this symbol.

Comment: Look at these links, they are very similar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032987/how-to-solve-mach-o-linker-error-in-ios7-xcode-5-0-1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073146/mach-o-linker-error-xcode-5

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Teaching a man (or women) how to fish:

Usually Mach-O Linker Error means you have not included a header file for a function you are using in your code.

Easiest way is to copy that function or method call and paste into Xcode quick search using shift+command+O. This will search all frameworks (and header files), find that function or method call and show you its location (the header in this case):

In this case, this call belongs to the Accelerate framework so on top of your file, enter:

```
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
```

When doing quick search, you might have to get rid of leading underscore. In other words, search for vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888

Hope this helps

Comment: This isn't accurate. Linker errors of this nature are most frequently due to failing to link against the framework or library that provides a symbol you're using. If you fail to `#include` or `#import` the necessary header you're much more likely to get a warning along the lines of `warning: implicit declaration of function 'vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888' is invalid in C99`. Adding the missing `#include` or `#import` will address the compiler warning, but does nothing to address the linker error.

Comment: This is a good way of finding out which framework you're missing though

Comment: I can't find out the missing library, can you please tell me how to find out which library is missing.

Answer (score 12):

Google is your friend: someone else fixed this by adding the Accelerate framework to their project (and this does look like a framework error).

https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView/issues/5

Make sure you also have the QuartzCore framework included as well, as that is also required by that library.

Comment: It is not necessary to link against QuartzCore to use the Accelerate framework.

Comment: I didn't say it was. The library he's using - RNBlurModalView - requires both QuartzCore and Accelerate to function. Chances are good if one was left out, the other was too, so I added it as a note in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888() is not defined. See if the Accelerate framework is properly included in the project.